# Crear un programa que forme una pirámide en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo un programa en c# en **windows forms** pero no se como hacer o que me este faltando para que me cree la pirámide y esto es lo que llevo de mi programa:

```
int numFilas,a,espacio,aster;
numFilas = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

for (a = 1; a <= numFilas; a++)
{
  //Espacios en blanco
  for (espacio = 0; espacio < numFilas; espacio++)
  {
     textBox3.Text = numFilas.ToString();
  }

  //Asteriscos
  for (aster= 0; aster <(a*2);espacio++)
  {
     this.textBox3.Text = " * " +espacio;
  }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ese textbox es multilinea? donde estas mandando los saltos de linea?

Comment: primero da un recorrido como te dicen en el comentario anterior, despues agrega el resultado que estas obteniendo hasta el momento, en una hoja imagina como se irian agregando los asteriscos, digamos primer linea num de especios en igual a longitud del texto menos un asterisco, siguiente linea eliminas agregas un asterisco, y asi de esta manera identificaras tus variables,.. para salto de linea se agrega \n .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenes que tener en cuenta cuantos asteriscos y espacios en blanco vas a tener por cada linea, te dejo

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        int numFilas, a;
        numFilas = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        for (a = 1; a <= numFilas; a++)
        {                
                int filasRestantes = numFilas;

                //En la primer linea siempre va un solo asterisco, en las demás deberían ser numeros impares.

                int cantAstericos = 1;
                if (a > 1) {
                        cantAstericos = (a + 1);
                        filasRestantes = numFilas - a;
                }

                //Agrego al textbox la linea: espacios en blanco + asteriscos + salto de linea 

                textBox3.Text += agregarEspaciosEnBlanco(filasRestantes) + agregarAsteriscos(cantAstericos) + "\r\n"; 
            }

    // Funcion que devuelve string con la cantidad de asteriscos

      public string agregarAsteriscos(int cantidad) {
                string res = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
                    res += "*";
                } 
                return res;
            }

    // Funcion que devuelve string con la cantidad de espacios en blanco

            public string agregarEspaciosEnBlanco(int cantidad)
            {
                string res = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++)
                {
                    res += " ";
                }
                return res;
            }
```

Deberías adaptar la cantidad de asteriscos que querés por fila, eso va a determinar la medida que va a crecer la pirámide fila tras fila, pero el concepto está claro.

Saludos!